# Cloning Linux partitions to external hdd

Tags: linux, copy, dump, disk

I want to copy Linux Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my hard disk to external hard disk. The purpose is to have exact OS bootable from external hdd on another PC.
[Here are listed Disk Drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGThP.png) , Ubuntu is installed on 1,0TB Hard Disk.

Partition 1 is NTFS created and used by Windows, [this is Partition 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Dfn.png) , and this is Partition 3: h??p://imgur.com/PY0tujU.

External hard disk is here: h??p://imgur.com/51mVrO2

How can I make exact same bootable Linux on my external hard disk? (using disk dump)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you should have a clone software and then things will be easier. For example, when you use AOMEI Backupper to clone OS, it will automatically pack up your system partition and system reserved partition (both make a complete OS package), copying everything here bit by bit.